Computed on a model value?
In my component I define a model:
const model = defineModel({
    type: Number,
});

I want the model value to be based upon an inputs value, so I have an input:
const input = ref(null);

This is bound to a text input with v-model:
<input v-model="input" />

Then I set the model to be based upon the input (this is a basic example of manipulation that I need to do):
model.value = computed(() => Number(input.value));

But I am having issues with the model updating in the parent component in development (works in build).
{{ someNumber }} //does not update
<MyComponent v-model="someNumber" />

This is very strange as it works when I run a build but not in dev, can anyone shed any light on this?

creating a defineModel and then setting it equal to be the computed of a ref is undocumented behavior that almost certainly shouldn't be done.  I suggest simplifying to <input v-model="model" type="number">

@yoduh, this does not give the desired effect of having a display value and a model with a modified value of the display value

I agree with @yoduh, emitting the computed is fragile (as you are experiencing). Your code is shorthand for emit('update:modelValue, computed(() => Number(input.value))'), it is hard to see where this would make sense. Reactivity between components is typically expressed in data flow or events, not through reactive objects. So you could replace it with a watcher (watchEffect(() => model.value = Number(...))) or use the update:modelValue event of the input. Also, v-model modifiers might work in your scenario.

If you want to get a modified value, instead of assigning the value
from a computed property, you can add the @input event listener:
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';

const model = defineModel({
    type: Number,
});

const input = ref(null);

function updateHandler(e) {
  // you can do any conversion here
  model.value = e.target.value * 10;
}

</script>

<template>
  <input type="number" v-model="input" @input="updateHandler" />
</template>

playground

You cannot reset 1 prop to 1 ref in core props is 1 reactivity if you try to fix it it will overwrite computed written in defineModel and will not work. you can only emit it by 1 follower
watchEffect(() => {
  model.value = Number(input.value)
})

